# setSize of JPanel after initialisation

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am bringing in a ResultSet to show the contents of my table. thing is that though the results are showing i have been trying to resize the height of the JPanel so that it shows once it is populated. I tried using `setSize(300, y)` in the `while(ResultSet.next)` loop and also tried it outside of the loop. but nothing gives.
Here is my code:

```
package SimpleCRUD;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ShowContactsFrame extends JFrame {
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints Constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    JLabel lblFname, lblLname, lblPhoneNumber;
    Statement st;
    String showAll = "SELECT * FROM `contacts`.`contacts`;";
    ResultSet rt;
    int y = 0;

    public ShowContactsFrame() {
        super("Contact List");
        try {
            AppCRUD initCRUD = new AppCRUD();
            rt = initCRUD.DBhandle.createStatement().executeQuery(showAll);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
        add(panel);
        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        lblFname = new JLabel("lblFname");
        lblLname = new JLabel("lblLname");
        lblPhoneNumber = new JLabel("lblPhoneNumber");

        Insets inset = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);

        Constraint.insets = inset;

        try {
            while (rt.next()) {
                Constraint.gridx = 0;
                Constraint.gridy = y;
                panel.add(new JLabel(rt.getString(2)), Constraint);
                Constraint.gridx = 1;
                Constraint.gridy = y;
                panel.add(new JLabel(rt.getString(3)), Constraint);
                Constraint.gridx = 2;
                Constraint.gridy = y;
                panel.add(new JLabel(rt.getString(4)), Constraint);
                y++;
                panel.setSize(300, y);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, y);

    }

}
```

Comment: Some random thoughts:  1) Layouts will generally honor preferred size over size.  2) Don't extend `(J)Frame` unless adding functionality.  3) Follow the common nomenclature for package (class/attribute..) names - especially for code intended for public viewing.  4) Why continue with anything after the first `catch`?  5) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Obviously, you would need to hard code some data. 6) Why not supply the frame as the parent of the `JOptionPane` instead of `null`?

Comment: 7) Why declare & instantiate the 3 labels and not do anything with them?  Are they intended to be table headers?  Speaking of which..  8) A JTable would be a natural component to display a ResultSet.  9) GUI construction should be done **on** the EDT.  Querying the DB should be done **off** the EDT.  10) I'm not sure what you expect to achieve with the call to `panel.setSize(300, y);`, since `y` will equal the number of 'rows' added to the panel.  1 pixel per row?

Comment: the three `JLabel` were actually for testing. i did not delete the code after use. Thank you for telling me about JTable and catching the bug for setSize. i now understand why the width was set to 300 yet the heught was barely increasing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the size of the panel you should use `setPreferredSize()` instead of `setSize()` in order as below.

```
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You have to do it this way since the component is controlled by a layout manager and therefore it ignores calls to `setSize()`. Which then is only used if you `setLayout()` to null, i.e. you use no manager.

Comment: Setting the preferred size should be avoided wherever possible.  I am not convinced it is necessary in this GUI, though short of an SSCCE from the OP (which is unlikely, given they seem to have solved their major query) I would not investigate it further.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson aha I understand. Though in this case it was a must, I think. I have noticed the panel was being set into BorderLayout NORTH position, thus it always had a minimal size. Whereas if it was placed into CENTER the preferred size would be unnecessary since the panel would take all that the frame would allow.

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is that you call pack() on the JFrame once you have built your GUI elements and set the sizes.

Comment: As per JavaDoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29 "Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents." Which means that every component inside it will be resized -- including your JPanel.

Comment: @ Prometheus87 and move "setVisible(true);" behind "JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, y);" should be pack() then setVisible(true);

Comment: I believe pack() automatically does setVisible(true)